# JWT: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Secret'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jwt, dotenv

I'm using dotenv to declare JWT_SECRET env variable and It's showing the error mentioned in title.

**.env**

```
NODE_ENV="development"
JWT_SECRET="mySecretString"
```

**environment.d.ts**

```
import { Secret } from 'jwt-promisify'

declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
        interface ProcessEnv {
            JWT_SECRET: Secret,
            NODE_ENV: 'development' | 'production',
            PORT?: number | string
        }
    }
}

export {}
```

I'm using in my routes file im signing token with `JWT_SECRET`

**route.ts**

```js
const token = await jwt.sign({ id: newUser.id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
```

Here intellisense is working but when I run the app or compile it the error appears.

**error**

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Secret'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Secret'.

32         const token = await jwt.sign({ id: newUser.id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: do you use `import dotenv from 'dotenv'       
dotenv.config()` in the top of file?

Comment: yes i'm using it in app.ts

Comment: I think you should use in every file that you want use `process.env`

Comment: I don't think so because when i was using Node.js in previous project i just required dotenv in `app.js` only then it worked with other files as well

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
  jwt.sign(data, process.env.SIGNATURE_KEY as string, {
        expiresIn: '30d',
        algorithm: "HS256"
    }, (err, encoded)=>{
        err ? reject(err) : resolve(encoded)
    })
```

For Typescript, I think Type casting works. I also didn't implement async-await because the sign method wasn't hinted as a `Promise`. But I guess it works too!

Answer (score 3):

## First solution

just use `!` right after `process.env.JWT_KEY`
actually, exclamation (!) says, hey typescript, don't worry, don't check this.

```js
const userJwt = jwt.sign({
   id: newUser.id 
}, process.env.JWT_KEY!);
```

And in the startup project(`index.ts`), when I want to load the database config, etc add the below condition

```js
‍‍‍//index.ts
const start = async () => {
  try {
    if(!process.env.JWT_KEY){
      throw new Error('JWT_KEY must be defined')
    }
    //Connect to database or ...
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

## Second solution

Because if you check the `JWT_KEY` before using `jwt.sign` like the below code, the problem will be solved without using `!` after `process.env.JWT_KEY`, but the first solution is better

```
if(!process.env.JWT_KEY){
  throw new Error('JWT_KEY must be defined')
}
const userJwt = jwt.sign({
  id: user.id,
}, process.env.JWT_KEY);
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem here is that typeof process.env.JWT_SECRET is either string or undefined.
So you could do:

```
const token = await jwt.sign({ id: newUser.id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET || "")
```

Comment: Do you seriously suggest to sign with an empty (or any other hardcoded) string?

Comment: I was just pointing out the issue, he can manage it however he wants. Anyhow, please add your suggestion too